# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out on Documentum 6.5, JBoss-4.2.0.GA_CP01 Tomcat-5.5 (files with 1025 bytes)

Tags: documentum

Through an application in C/C++, which uses Axis2 for communication with Documentum (6.5), I've encountered a bug when I can not find solution.

When trying to insert a document in Documentum 6.5, I'm getting the following error:

HTTP/1.1 500 Error Interno del Servidor Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.0.GA_CP01 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_4_2_0_GA_CP01 date=200709131706)/Tomcat-5.5 Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2015 07:15:28 GMT Connection: close

17c S:ClientCouldn't create SOAP message due to exception: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

I have found that this happens when the file is 1025 bytes or a multiple of 1025. If I change the binary stored in Documentum, making a different size to 1025 bytes, I get no error.

I've located some bug but does not indicate the solution or possible cause: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47797

Anyone can perform a similar test? What JBoss component is responsible for reading the binary file?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you on the latest 6.5 patch level?

Comment: I haven't installed any patch.

Comment: OK, so... Documentum 6.5 is _more than 7 years old_. You should at least consider upgrading to Service Pack 3, and then install patch 24. Even then you will have a version which is 3 years old since 6.5 SP3 reached end of life in August 2012. The best option would of course be to upgrade to the latest 6.7 version, or better still, version 7.2. I looked through the release doc for 6.5sp3p24, but couldn't find anything about the problem you have. That doesn't mean it has _not_ been corrected in more recent Documentum versions, though.